# HorizontalPodAutoscaler: missing field "conditions"

Tags: kubernetes, horizontal-pod-autoscaling

Friends, I am trying to implement a HPA following the [hpa tutorial](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/run-application/horizontal-pod-autoscale-walkthrough/) of k8s and I am having the following error:

**ValidationError(HorizontalPodAutoscaler.status): missing required field "conditions" in io.k8s.api.autoscaling.v2beta2.HorizontalPodAutoscalerStatus**.

I couldn't find anything about this field "conditions". Does someone have an idea what I may be doing wrong? Here its the YAML of my HPA:

```
apiVersion: autoscaling/v2beta2
kind: HorizontalPodAutoscaler
metadata:
  name: {{ .Values.name }}
spec:
  scaleTargetRef:
    apiVersion: apps/v1
    kind: Deployment
    name: {{ .Values.name}}
  minReplicas: {{ .Values.deployment.minReplicas }}
  maxReplicas: {{ .Values.deployment.maxReplicas }}
  metrics:
  - type: Resource
    resource:
      name: cpu
      target:
        type: Utilization
        averageUtilization: 50
status:
  observedGeneration: 1
  lastScaleTime: <some-time>
  currentReplicas: 2
  desiredReplicas: 2
  currentMetrics:
  - type: Resource
    resource:
      name: cpu
      current:
        averageValue: 0
```

And here the manifest of my deployment:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: {{ .Values.name }}
spec:
  replicas: {{ .Values.deployment.replicaCount }}
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: {{ .Values.labels}}
  template:
    metadata:
      annotations:
        checksum/config: {{ include (print $.Template.BasePath "/configmap.yaml") . | sha256sum }}
      labels:
        app: {{ .Values.labels }}
    spec:
      initContainers:
      - name: check-rabbitmq
        image: {{ .Values.initContainers.image }}
        command: ['sh', '-c',
        'until wget http://$(RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_USER):$(RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_PASS)@rabbitmq:15672/api/aliveness-test/%2F; 
        do echo waiting; sleep 2; done;']
        envFrom:
        - configMapRef:
            name: {{ .Values.name }}
      - name: check-mysql
        image: {{ .Values.initContainers.image }}
        command: ['sh', '-c', 'until nslookup mysql-primary.default.svc.cluster.local; do echo waiting for mysql; sleep 2; done;']
      containers:
      - name: {{ .Values.name }}
        image: {{ .Values.deployment.image }}
        ports:
        - containerPort: {{ .Values.ports.containerPort }} 
        resources:
          limits:
            cpu: 500m
          requests:
            cpu: 200m
        envFrom:
        - configMapRef:
            name: {{ .Values.name }}
```

Answer (score 3):

#### Background

Not sure, why you want to create `HPA` with `status` section. If you would remove this section it will create `HPA` without any issue.

In documentation [Understanding Kubernetes Objects - Object Spec and Status](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/overview/working-with-objects/kubernetes-objects/#object-spec-and-status) you can find information:

> Almost every Kubernetes object includes two nested object fields that govern the object's configuration: the object `spec` and the object `status`. For objects that have a `spec`, you have to set this when you create the object, providing a description of the characteristics you want the resource to have: its desired state.

> The `status` describes the current state of the object, **supplied and updated by the Kubernetes system and its components.** The Kubernetes control plane continually and actively manages every object's actual state to match the desired state you supplied.

Your situation is partially described in [Appendix: Horizontal Pod Autoscaler Status Conditions](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/run-application/horizontal-pod-autoscale-walkthrough/#appendix-horizontal-pod-autoscaler-status-conditions)

> When using the `autoscaling/v2beta2` form of the `HorizontalPodAutoscaler`, you will be able to see status conditions set by Kubernetes on the HorizontalPodAutoscaler. These status conditions indicate whether or not the `HorizontalPodAutoscaler` is able to `scale`, and whether or not it is currently restricted in any way.

#### Example from my GKE test cluster

As I mention before, if you will remove `status` section, you will be able to create `HPA`.

```
$ kubectl apply -f - <<EOF
> apiVersion: autoscaling/v2beta2
> kind: HorizontalPodAutoscaler
> metadata:
>   name: hpa-apache
> spec:
>   scaleTargetRef:
>     apiVersion: apps/v1
>     kind: Deployment
>     name: php-apache
>   minReplicas: 1
>   maxReplicas: 3
>   metrics:
>   - type: Resource
>     resource:
>       name: cpu
>       target:
>         type: Utilization
>         averageUtilization: 50
> EOF
horizontalpodautoscaler.autoscaling/hpa-apache created
```

Following `HPA` documentation, I've created `PHP Deployment`.

```
$ kubectl apply -f https://k8s.io/examples/application/php-apache.yaml
deployment.apps/php-apache created
service/php-apache created
```

When you executed command `kubectl autoscale` you have created `HPA` for deployment `php-apache`

```
$ kubectl autoscale deployment php-apache --cpu-percent=50 --min=1 --max=10
horizontalpodautoscaler.autoscaling/php-apache autoscaled
```

Now you are able to see `hpa` resource using `kubectl get hpa` or `kubectl get hpa.v2beta2.autoscaling`. Output is the same.

First command will show all `HPA` objects with any `apiVersion` (`v2beta2`, `v2beta1`, etc), second command will show `HPA` only with `apiVersion: hpa.v2beta2.autoscaling`. My cluster as default is using `v2beta2` so output of both commands is the same.

```
$ kubectl get hpa
NAME         REFERENCE               TARGETS   MINPODS   MAXPODS   REPLICAS   AGE
php-apache   Deployment/php-apache   0%/50%    1         10        1          76s
$ kubectl get hpa.v2beta2.autoscaling
NAME         REFERENCE               TARGETS   MINPODS   MAXPODS   REPLICAS   AGE
php-apache   Deployment/php-apache   0%/50%    1         10        1          84s
```

When execute command below, new file with `hpa` configuration will be created. This file is based on already created `HPA` from previous `kubectl autoscale` command.

```
$ kubectl get hpa.v2beta2.autoscaling -o yaml > hpa-v2.yaml
# If I would use command `kubectl get hpa hpa-apache > hpa-v2.yaml` file would look the same
$ cat hpa-v2.yaml
apiVersion: v1
items:
- apiVersion: autoscaling/v2beta2
  kind: HorizontalPodAutoscaler
  metadata:
...
status:
    conditions:
    - lastTransitionTime: "2020-12-11T10:44:43Z"
      message: recent recommendations were higher than current one, applying the highest
        recent recommendation
      reason: ScaleDownStabilized
      status: "True"
      type: AbleToScale
      ...
    currentMetrics:
    - resource:
        current:
          averageUtilization: 0
          averageValue: 1m
```

#### Conclusion

The `status` describes the current state of the object, **supplied and updated by the Kubernetes system and it's components.**

If you want to create resource based on `YAML` with `status`, you have to provide value in `status.conditions`, where `condition` require `array` value.

```
status:
  conditions:
  - lastTransitionTime: "2020-12-11T10:44:43Z"
```

#### Quick solution

Just remove `status` section, from your YAML.

Let me know if you still encounter any issue after removing `status` section from YAML manifest.